# IndexError: list index out of range PythonWin

Tags: python, arcgis

Tengo el siguiente problema,
como dar argumentos 3 y 8 para a y b?

```
import sys
a = int(sys.argv[1])
b = int(sys.argv[2])
c = a + b
print "The sum is {0}.".format(c)

Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 2, in <module>
    a = int(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes pasar los argumentos en la línea de comandos.

En Linux es asi:

```
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects$ python script.py 3 8
```

En Windows será algo asi (supongo; no tengo Windows):

```
C:\PycharmProjects> python script.py 3 8
```

(Suponiendo que guardas tu código en el archivo script.py)

Si lo ejecutas desde dentro del IDE, tienes que crear una configuración apropiada, lo que varia de IDE en IDE. Puedes hacer otra pregunta si deseas ayuda para tu IDE especifica.